# gauss jordan matrix involving parameter $k$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, gaussian-elimination

Could anyone help me in solving this matrix?

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
      k+2&   k-1&   k&  2\\
      0&   k+2&  2&  0\\
      0&  0& k^2+k-2&  k+2
    \end{array}\right]$$

Find $k$ for which the system has:

a) exactly one solution

b) infinitely many solutions

c) no solutions

I am new in linear algebra and having trouble getting my head around this.
I am particularly confused with part (b).

Comment: Since your system is already triangular, you will be in situation (a) if and only if all diagonal coefficients are nonzero. With those cases aside, only finitely many values of $k$ remain (where at least one diagonal entry is zero), which values you can treat individually.

Comment: I am actually quite confused with the question (b) where if k = -2, i would get a column (first one) of 0s. so in this case, is it correct to say that x = t where t is real and a parameter? as I am not sure whether in this case the system is consistent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$A = \begin{bmatrix} k+2 & k-1 & k\\ 0 & k+2 & 2\\ 0 & 0 & k^2 + k-2\end{bmatrix}$$ and $$[A \mid B]  = \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} k+2 & k-1 & k & 2\\ 0 & k+2 & 2  & 0\\ 0 & 0 & k^2 +k-2 & k+2\end{array}\right].$$

It is true that a system has a solution (not necessarily unique), iff: $$\boxed{\text{rank }A = \text{rank }[A\mid B]}\tag{1}.$$

- If the system has infinitely many solutions, then it must hold $\det A = 0$ and the $(1)$. We notice that $\det A = 0$ for $k = 1,-2$.
  Try to find the rank of $A$ and $[A\mid B]$ in each case.